# How to save duplicates only?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I made code to remove duplicates from col in my xlsx file.

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook


def delete_duplicates(nazov_suboru, cielovy_subor,riadok):
    data = pd.read_excel(nazov_suboru)
    print("chvilelenku pockaj")
    data.drop_duplicates(subset=[riadok], keep=False, inplace=True)
    data.to_excel(cielovy_subor, index=False)
    print("done")
```

It save the unique data. But I need the opposite. To only save the duplicated ones. Cant figure it out. Any ideas please /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = data[data.duplicated(subset=[riadok], keep=False)]
```

would keep the duplicated rows.

See [pandas.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `keep="last"` to only save objects that are duplicates?

Comment: last : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.

False : Mark all duplicates as True. @TheLazyScripter Op wants to keep the duplicated ones

Comment: Ah, I see that. Thanks for the clarification!